# Regular expression to remove comment

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which finds all the comments in text.
For example all between `/* */`. 
Example:

> /* Hello  */

When I do this:`/\*.*\*/`, it behaves odd and nothing is shown. What is wrong with it?

EDIT: The comments can be spread across multiple lines

Comment: It could be that `/` is the delimiter of the regex. Maybe `/\/\*.*\*\//` this will work.

Comment: Please also include the language that you are trying to do this in and some test code.

Comment: that works here..which language are u using?

Comment: Well not exactly a language, but I am trying to edit code on Sublime Text2

Comment: @flec Nope. regex `/\*\*` detects all text `/**` so it is not a delimiter

Comment: Try `/\*.*?\*/`, if it works, I'll post an explanation.

Comment: @Jatin Maybe it is because you regex is greedy. Try `/\*.*?\*/`

Comment: @Dukeling That didnt work

Comment: @flec Odd but that doesnt work either. I will rather write a small scala script to do it than in sublime text itself

Comment: Is the comment really on a single line like in your example?  By default, `.` does not match line breaks.  Thus you would have to enable multi-line mode to match a multi-line comment.

Comment: Nope. it does have line breaks. @dan1111 awesome!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Unlike the example posted above, you were trying to match comments that spanned multiple lines.  By default, `.` does not match a line break.  Thus you have to enable multi-line mode in the regex to match multi-line comments.

Also, you probably need to use `.*?` instead of `.*`.  Otherwise it will make the largest match possible, which will be everything between the first open comment and the last close comment.

I don't know how to enable multi-line matching mode in Sublime Text 2.  I'm not sure it is available as a mode.  However, you can insert a line break into the actual pattern by using CTRL + Enter.  So, I would suggest this alternative:

```
/\*(.|\n)*?\*/
```

If Sublime Text 2 doesn't recognize the `\n`, you could alternatively use CTRL + Enter to insert a line break in the pattern, in place of `\n`.

Comment: [Some](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html) [references](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html).

Comment: So what will itbe like in this case?

Comment: `/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/` This did the job

Comment: This could be improved, I found some issues with php block comments using this, I modified it and a `preg_replace('/(\/\*.*?\*\/)/is',' ',$contents)`worked really well for me

Comment: @Idealcastle, note that comment matching is not something that a regex can handle well in the general case.  This particular question is about text matching in an editor, an acceptable use of regexes since there is an element of human review of the matching.  However, in your PHP code a regex will be problematic unless your input is a clearly defined subset of all possible comment constructs.  If you need to do this robustly, use a parser.

Comment: This fails if the `/* comment */` is in quotes. See https://regex101.com/r/GBwfJq/1

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this problem several years ago and [wrote an entire article about it](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html).

If you don't have access to non-greedy matching (not all regex libraries support non-greedy) then you should use this regex:

```
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

If you do have access to non-greedy matching then you can use:

```
/\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/
```

Also, keep in mind that regular expressions are just a heuristic for this problem.  Regular expressions don't support cases in which something appears to be a comment to the regular expression but actually isn't:

```java
someString = "An example comment: /* example */";

// The comment around this code has been commented out.
// /*
some_code();
// */
```

Comment: As mentioned - this fails if the `/* comment */` is in quotes. See https://regex101.com/r/9BEuK2/1

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add for HTML Comments is is this

```
\<!--(.|\n)*?-->
```

Answer (score 2):

> *Just an additionnal note about using regex to remove comments inside a programming language file.*

**Warning!**

Doing this you must not forget the case where you have the string `/*` or `*/` inside a string in the code - like `var string = "/*";` - (we never know if you parse a huge code that is not yours)!

So the best is to parse the document with a programming language and have a boolean to save the state of an open string (and ignore any match inside open string).

Again a string delimited by `"` can contain a `\"` so pay attention with the regex!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write a regular expression that would be able to correctly find all comments, or even one type of comments - single-line or multiline.

Regular expressions can only provide a partial match, one that would would cover perhaps 90% of all cases, but that's it.

The syntax for regular expression is so complex, it is only possible to identify them correctly in 100% of cases by doing a full expression evaluation, which in turn is based on tokenizing the code. The latter is a huge task, which is implemented by all AST parsers today. See [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/)

Only a proper-written AST parser can tell you precisely where all regular expressions are located in your code. You would have to write a parser then based on that.

Or, you could use one of the existing libraries that already do all that, like [decomment](https://github.com/vitaly-t/decomment).

---

RegEx examples where any head-on approach is going to stumble, being unable to tell a regular expression from a comment block:

- `/\//` - it will think this reg-ex is a single-line comment
- `/\/*/` - it will think this reg-ex opens a multi-line comment

Comment: I don't see why it should be impossible. Can you please show an example of code that you think isn't easy to handle?

Comment: It's true that it's not easy to get this right without a proper parser, but it's certainly not "impossible" by any stretch. If you just need this for a one-off task, it's easier to write the functionality you need rather than roll out a full-blown parser for your language!

Comment: The OP wants to match code comments *using a text editor*.  A perfectly reasonable, useful thing to do.

Comment: @dan1111 I have added examples of where a head-on approach is going to stumble.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the limitations of a regex in this context.  But the OP is not proposing to, say, put this in production code.  Using a regex to do some quick hacking in a text editor is a totally different task.  You can manually check whether it worked.  You can get away with not handling every single edge case ever.  And a parser is probably not a practical alternative to what the OP has in mind.

Comment: Shouldn't say this is impossible. For some reason, this is the thumbnail answer for this question on google (and this was the first result for "regex to remove comments") so a lot of people will see this answer and give up.

Comment: @ColeHenrich So I removed the `impossible` part, but the the main message remains, explaining why you cannot do it with just RegEx in JavaScript. You do need to tokenize the code, in order to avoid breaking RexEx statements inside JavaScript.

Comment: I see. Thanks for updating it! I'm surprised at the quick response, even on so old a question - that's admirable dedication.

Answer (score 0):

The answer which user1919238 wrote works. Just corroborating that here, although the many upvotes probably do give you a clue.
It got rid of all these annoying block comments, put here just to show the usefulness/thank user1919238 for saving time:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,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 */

/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,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 */

/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,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 */
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]    if you want to replace the obnoxious comment from flutter main.dart,
Press cmd +r on mac or cntrl+ r on windows,
type //.* into the box above, leave the box below empty
click .* on the replace dialog, to activate regex,
then click on replace all. this will remove all your comments, you can do this if you want to remove all comments in any file in a flutter.
Additional, to reformat the main.dart
press cmd+a on mac and cntrl+a on windows,
then press cmd+alt(option)+l or cntrl+alt+l, this will reformat the code.
I will attach a picture of the main. dart, the green .* at the top of the page is what you will press to activate the regex.